# Packages in TOC in WinEdt

Tags: winedt

How can I change the tree setting to show packages used in the tex file?
I am using this but it doesn't work very well:

```
  END="\usepackage[?]"
ITEM="\usepackage[?]"
// Disabled: Change Mode from ? to TeX to enable this item
MODE_FILTER="TeX"
CASE_SENSITIVE=1
BEGINNING_OF_LINE_ONLY=1
CURRENT_DOCUMENT_ONLY=1
ALL_OPENED_DOCUMENTS=0
COMPLETE_PROJECT_TREE=1
ICON="Figure"
LEVEL=96
CAPTION="%[!|Exe('%b\Macros\Gather\FigTab.edt');|];%$('FigTabGather');"
MAX_LINE_SPAN=99
ON_CTRL_CLICK_MACRO="GlobalMark;TreeTrack(2);"
ON_CLICK_MACRO="TreeTrack(2,1);"
ON_DBL_CLICK_MACRO="TreeTrack(2,2);"
ACTION="Find"
  IMAGE="Find"
  MACRO="TreeTrack(2);"
SUBSTITUTION="\label{*}"
  SUB_FIND="\\label\{*\}"
  SUB_REPLACE=""
  SUB_REG_EX=1
  SUB_CASE_SENSITIVE=1
SUBSTITUTION="  "
  SUB_FIND=" +{ }"
  SUB_REPLACE=" "
  SUB_REG_EX=1
  SUB_CASE_SENSITIVE=1
SUBSTITUTION="\dots"
  SUB_FIND="\dots"
  SUB_REPLACE="..."
  SUB_REG_EX=0
  SUB_CASE_SENSITIVE=1
SUBSTITUTION="\ldots"
  SUB_FIND="\ldots"
  SUB_REPLACE="..."
  SUB_REG_EX=0
  SUB_CASE_SENSITIVE=1
 END="\usepackage[?]"
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please remove the lines you've added in `Tree.ini` and just after the line

```
[NAVIGATION_BAR]
```

add the following ones

```
BRANCH="Packages-TeX"
  BRANCH_CAPTION="Packages"
  BRANCH_MODE_FILTER="TeX|DTX;INS;STY;AUX"
  BRANCH_ICON="Gather"
  BRANCH_SORTED=0
  BRANCH_CASE_SENSITIVE=1
  BRANCH_IGNORE_COMMENTS=1
  BRANCH_IGNORE_VERBATIM=1
  BRANCH_EXPANDED=0
  ITEM="\usepackage[?]{?}"
    ALT="\usepackage{?}"
    MODE_FILTER="TeX"
    CASE_SENSITIVE=1
    BEGINNING_OF_LINE_ONLY=1
    CURRENT_DOCUMENT_ONLY=1
    ALL_OPENED_DOCUMENTS=0
    COMPLETE_PROJECT_TREE=1
    ICON="Package"
    LEVEL=0
    CAPTION="%?"
    BALANCED="{}\"
    MAX_LINE_SPAN=10
    ON_CTRL_CLICK_MACRO="GlobalMark;TreeTrack(2);"
    ON_CLICK_MACRO="TreeTrack(2,1);"
    ON_DBL_CLICK_MACRO="TreeTrack(2,2);"
    ACTION="Find"
      IMAGE="Find"
      MACRO="TreeTrack(2);"
    SUBSTITUTION="  "
      SUB_FIND=" +{ }"
      SUB_REPLACE=" "
      SUB_REG_EX=1
      SUB_CASE_SENSITIVE=1
  END="\usepackage[?]{?}"
END="Packages-TeX"
```

Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to apply the changes.

This is an example of what you can get now in the Tree panel:

[image]

Just remember to load the packages one by one, otherwise you will have a comma-separated list as an item.

Comment: thank you very much! what do you mean by loading packages one by one?

Comment: @user114781 You're welcome. I mean if you write `\usepackage{float,caption}` you will have "float,caption" in the Tree and there is no way to overcome this. :-)